# making simple app for both iphone/android(super basic)

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Basically i need 2 apps that work on both Android/IOS with a simple sign in button and 5 push notifications that can be dowloaded for a little project.

The conclusion I reached was html? and some way to let the user download the files without needing hosting etc.

perhaps someone knows of a more efficient way to do this? or since its non profit get some skeleton code for each os and then just add buttons from x code and android api?

Comment: 1. How do you plan on downloading a push notification?
2. How are you going to use HTML to communicate with an app?
3. What files are you downloading?

Comment: push notification as in an application function. html renders its own things? and the apk file etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are asking but, you can use 'Phonegap'  which is cross platform and can use web development languages such as html, JavaScript, and css.

Comment: yes this is looking like the best route. Thanks for info